# How to fix Cannot access disposed object of Interface

Tags: c#, exception, interface, objectdisposedexception

Has anyone been able to fix the issue :

**"Cannot access a disposed object.\r\nObject name: 'IService'."}   System.Exception {System.ObjectDisposedException}**

**IService** is the interface I'm using. See code block.

```
internal partial class Controller
{
   private readonly IService _service;

   public Controller(IService service)
   {
       _service = service;   
   }

   private void ConfigService()
   {
      try
      {
          using (var scope = _service.CreateScopes()) // this is where the error is showing
          {
             
                
          }
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
         Debug.WriteLine($"[Controller_Debug]: DataLoad exception: {ex.Message}");
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems, that *disposed* `service` is passed into `Controller` constructor.

Comment: Check for null before using the object or use: '_service?.CreateScopes()'

Comment: @Rufw91 that scenario would cause a `NullReferenceException`, not an `ObjectDisposedException`

Comment: any clues on how `IService` is registered, and what else is using it? it *looks* like another code path has been given the same `IService` instance (perhaps it is registered as a singleton?), and has disposed the instance - which it probably shouldn't have done if it doesn't own the lifetime

Comment: I assume you have a singleton somewhere that is disposable... And some code somewhere disposed it.

Comment: @Marc True, he will need to check for null as well as if object is disposed.